# Pass Form Element Value to Ajax Post Method on an onChange Event

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onchange

so I have a this form select which I want to pass the value in ajax using the onChange event.

```
<select name="someName" id="someName" onChange="changeSomething()">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="4">Value 4</option>
</select>
    <div id="base_url"></div>
    <script>
        function changeSomething() {       
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://example.com/ajax/command/change_something.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    "key": "2qsKeJrQNLE1GoFrnWpL",
                    "base_url": "http://example.com/",
                    "id": $("#someName").val() //  I want to get the value of this one
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#base_url").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Is there another way to pass the value of any form element especially on an onChange Event? Am I doing it wrong? Please help!! T_T

Comment: You're doing it correctly *(assuming you're using jQuery)*. What result are you getting?

Comment: but it returns an error like this on my firebug ---> Uncaught ReferenceError: NUivDsF5hTz6J3YJc0IF is not defined 19:76
(anonymous function) 19:76
o jquery.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.js:2
c.addEventListener.B jquery.js:2

Comment: Is there more to your code?

Comment: That error doesn't seem like it is related to the `$("someName").val()` part of the code, which should work fine. What happens if you remove that and just hardcode it as `"id": "1"`?

Comment: I think you're right Crazy Train... it's not producing an error now! :) thanks btw!! weird...

Comment: I don't know why it produces an error on page load.... cuz when I try to change something on the form Select... the error is still there.. but the change_something.php returns the values i want though... but still the error isn't gone.

Comment: On page load? Wait, exactly when does the error occur? Is there any other JS on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your form elements with the $.serializeArray() JQuery function

See the doc at 
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 0):

check this one:

```
   <select name="someName" id="someName" onChange="changeSomething(this.value)">
   function changeSomething(id)
   "id": id
```

Comment: This post isn't clear at all. Please be more specific or else this answer may be deleted.

Comment: please check the question first. and update base on my answer.